# Ubuntu 12.10 Can't install any apps due Stranger error

Tags: software-center, gzip

I can't install any app in the Ubuntu, I can't even open the Software Center (It Crashes)

When I run sudo apt-get update, it shows me

```
W: Falhou ao buscar gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/br.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_quantal_universe_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum incorreto
```

Something like (in english)

```
W: Failed to Download gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/br.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_quantal_universe_binary-i386_Packages  Wrong Hash Sum
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

do this in your terminal:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

sudo apt-get update
```

hope that solves your issue.